# Android project syncing Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

This is my build.gradle(Module:App) code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mashitha.smartwaterbottle"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev328-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
//Google play services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
}

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I get this Error, when i sync the project.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.0.

Please Give an answer for fixed this error.

Thank you

Comment: What is the version of your classpath for google-services?

Answer (score 0):

you applied two different versions of google play services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

please unify the API version to be latest version 15.0.1

also it is recommended to use latest version of  Firebase Cloud Services APIs

you could check it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)